# setAttribute() is not working

Tags: javascript, setattribute

Again, I am following my reference book and online references when using setAttribute: it simply does not work;

HTML:

```
    <div id="page">
        <h1 id="header"></h1>
        <h2 id="subheader"></h2>
        <p id="pone"></p>
        <ul >
            <li id="one" class="lit" >ad nauseum</li>
            <li id="two" class="lit">ad item</li>
            <li id="three" class="lit">ad item</li>
            <li id="four" class="lit">ad item</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <script src="js/DOM_js.js"></script>
```

The css:

```
  .lit { font-size: 14px;}
  .lite { font-size: 20px; font-style:italic;}
```

The js:

```
// Change class names of li
var alli = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
alert(alli.length);

// li one 
 var lione = document.getElementById("one"); 
lione.textContent = "First point: ";
 // Ask for first point
 var fpOne = prompt("What is your first point?");
//change li one text
lione.textContent += fpOne;
alli.setAttribute("class","lite");
```

the set attribute does not work even if I put the line right after the alert(): at which point the prompt doesn't work. 
I have even tried:

```
var alli = document.getElementsByTagName("li").setAttribute("class","lite");
alert(alli.length);
```

At which point nothing works.
I have even tried removing the original class attribute for the li tags as suggested in a similar stackoverflow question, all to no avail.

What is the correct setAttribute technique?

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a **list** of elements, not just one. You have to set the attribute on each element individually.

Comment: You've to set an attribute of an element, a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array. You need to iterate through the array

```
var alli = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < alli.length; i++) {
  alli[i].setAttribute("class", "lite");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and OP's next question is: "Why can't I `alli.pop()`?"

Answer (score 1):

If using jquery you need not to iterate:

```
$('li').attr('class', 'lite');
```